# SQL : Calculating employee utilization hours for each day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL : I have a table with employee working hours in StartTime and EndTime column. I want to calculate the working hours for each employee for each day even employee starts he's shift on one day and ends on next day.

```
|Employee |StartTime         |EndTime         |
|A        | 01/01/2001 23:00 |02/01/2001 10:00|
|B        | 01/01/2001 21:00 |01/01/2001 22:00|

Output:
|Employee |Date         |HoursWorked              
|A        | 01/01/2001  | 1         |
|A        | 02/01/2001  | 10        |
|B        | 01/01/2001  | 1         |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an approach using recursive CTEs:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
Employee NVARCHAR(10)
,StartTime DATETIME
,EndTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('A', '2001-01-01 23:00:00', '2001-01-03 10:00:00')
                     ,('A', '2001-01-05 21:00:00', '2001-01-06 22:00:00')
                     ,('A', '2001-01-07 21:00:00', '2001-01-08 22:00:00')
                     ,('B', '2001-01-01 21:00:00', '2001-01-01 22:00:00')
                     ,('B', '2001-01-02 21:00:00', '2001-01-03 02:00:00')
                     ,('C', '2001-01-03 02:00:00', '2001-01-04 00:00:00');

WITH cte AS(
  SELECT 1 AS lvl, Employee, CONVERT(DATE, StartTime) StartTime_DATE, StartTime, EndTime
    FROM @t AS t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT lvl + 1 AS lvl, c.employee, DATEADD(d, 1, c.StartTime_DATE) StartTime_DATE, c.StartTime, c.EndTime
    FROM cte AS c
    WHERE DATEADD(d, 1, c.StartTime_DATE) < c.EndTime
),
cteCalc AS(
  SELECT *
        ,CONVERT(DATE, StartTime) AS StartDate
        ,CASE WHEN lvl > 1 THEN CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, StartTime, StartTime_DATE), StartTime))) ELSE DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, StartTime, StartTime_DATE), StartTime) END AS StartTimeNew
        ,ISNULL(CONVERT(datetime, LEAD(StartTime_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY Employee, CONVERT(DATE, StartTime) ORDER BY StartTime_DATE)), EndTime) AS EndTimeNew
    FROM cte

)
SELECT Employee, StartTime_DATE AS StartDate, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTimeNew, EndTimeNew)/60.0 AS WorkHours
  FROM cteCalc
  ORDER BY Employee, StartTime_DATE
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Hey, this is one nice solution, but I imagine the database has multiple records per employee. Imagine the following test data:
`INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('A', '2001-01-01 23:00:00',  '2001-01-03 10:00:00'),
('A', '2001-01-05 21:00:00',  '2001-01-06 22:00:00'),
 ('A', '2001-01-07 21:00:00',  '2001-01-08 22:00:00');`. 

I think using **LEAD** is causing unexpected output between the different periods, but I can't seem to understand why does it behave like that?  (startTimeNew = legit start time of day, endTimeNew = midnight on the StartTime of new period).

Comment: I just modified the query and extended the LEAD Partitioning by the startdate - at first glance it looked OK now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) function

```
create table #employee (Employee varchar(10), StartTime datetime, EndTime datetime)
insert into #employee values ('A','2001-01-01 23:00', '2001-01-02 10:00')

select Employee, CAST(StartTime as DATE) [Date], DATEDIFF(HOUR,StartTime, EndTime)HoursWorked from #employee
```

Comment: This does not provide the required result: Employee A worked 1 hour on 1.1. and 10 hours on 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query -

```
create table #Employee (
     Employee varchar(10), StartTime smalldatetime      , EndTime smalldatetime
)
go

insert into #Employee   
select 'A'     , ' 01/01/2001 23:00', '02/01/2001 10:00' 
union all select 'B '     , '01/01/2001 21:00', '01/01/2001 22:00'   

select Employee ,  cast(StartTime as date) [Date] ,  datediff(hour,StartTime, EndTime)HoursWorked              
from #Employee 
where cast(StartTime as date) = cast(EndTime as date )
union all 
select Employee ,  cast(StartTime as date) [Date] ,    datediff(hour,StartTime, cast( concat(cast(StartTime as date) ,' 23:59:59' )as smalldatetime))  HoursWorked                  
from #Employee 
where cast(StartTime as date) <> cast(EndTime as date ) 
union all 
select Employee ,  cast(EndTime as date) [Date] ,    datediff(hour, cast( concat(cast(EndTime as date) ,' 00:00:00' )as smalldatetime) ,EndTime) HoursWorked                  
from #Employee 
where cast(StartTime as date) <> cast(EndTime as date )
```

Comment: Seems to work, but only if you stick to a maximum of two days... just as a test I changed employee Bs EndTime to 03.01. instead of 01.01. and I receive only 2 rows - one for 01.01. and one for 03.01.; my recursive CTE behaves a bit differently.

Comment: yes it will work for 2 days only. I dont think someone can work contentiously for more then 2 days :) ,  as the provided data is related to working hours.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of many situations where it's nice to have a calendar lookup table. There are numerous examples of calendar table scripts to build something as simple or as robust as you could want, but let's just pretend all you have is a list of dates in your calendar table.

Generating the temp tables and filling them with sample data...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CalendarLookupTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #CalendarLookupTable;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    EmployeeID INT NOT NULL,
    StartTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    EndTime DATETIME NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #TestData (EmployeeID, StartTime, EndTime) VALUES
    (1, '01-01-2001 23:00', '01-02-2001 10:00')
    ,(2, '01-01-2001 21:00', '01-01-2001 22:00')
    ,(3, '01-02-2001 21:00', '01-04-2001 22:00');


CREATE TABLE #CalendarLookupTable (
    consequtiveDate DATETIME NOT NULL
    );
INSERT INTO #CalendarLookupTable(consequtiveDate) VALUES
    ('01-01-2001')
    ,('01-02-2001')
    ,('01-03-2001')
    ,('01-04-2001')
```

Querying the tables (the table inside the select basically splits the datetime periods in time periods within the same day - then we count the datediff in hours between the start and end time period) - you could refactor as CTE.

```
SELECT
    rnd.EmployeeID
    ,CONVERT(date, rnd.StartTime)
    ,DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartTime, EndTime)
FROM
    (
    SELECT td.EmployeeID AS [EmployeeID]
          ,CASE WHEN CAST(td.StartTime AS DATE) = clt.consequtiveDate THEN td.StartTime
                WHEN CAST(td.EndTime AS DATE) = clt.consequtiveDate THEN CAST(CAST(td.EndTime AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
                ELSE CAST(clt.consequtiveDate AS DATETIME)
           END AS [StartTime]
           ,CASE WHEN CAST(td.StartTime AS DATE) = clt.consequtiveDate THEN CAST(DATEADD(day,1,CAST(td.StartTime AS DATE))AS DATETIME)
                WHEN CAST(td.EndTime AS DATE) = clt.consequtiveDate THEN td.EndTime
                ELSE CAST(DATEADD(day,1,clt.consequtiveDate) AS DATETIME)
            END AS [EndTime]
    FROM #TestData AS td
    JOIN #CalendarLookupTable AS clt
      ON clt.consequtiveDate BETWEEN CAST(td.StartTime AS DATE) AND CAST(td.EndTime AS DATE)
     ) AS rnd
```

I'm here for further clarifications, if needed. Hope it works for you. I guess it's a little bit more robust (works on every SQL Server (doesn't use concat)).

Edit: you can take a look at [this article on creating and using calendar tables in TSQL](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) . Why I think it would be better using a calendar lookup table? Imagine your business logic changes and you need to return not only the hours per day, but the wage the employee must receive - maybe working during the weekends and/or national holidays means bigger hourly wage? Using a calendar lookup table makes this very easy.

Edit2: [Sample table-valued function that returns a pretty awesome calendar lookup table](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519)

Answer (score 0):

Edit2: I eliminated the LEAD() function from the solution by Tyron78. This way it works with SQL-Server pre-2012 and performs better imho:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
    Employee NVARCHAR(10)
    ,StartTime DATETIME
    ,EndTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES   ('A', '2001-01-01 23:00:00', '2001-01-03 10:00:00')
        ,('A', '2001-01-05 21:00:00', '2001-01-06 22:00:00')
        ,('A', '2001-01-07 21:00:00', '2001-01-08 22:00:00')
        ,('B', '2001-01-01 21:00:00', '2001-01-01 22:00:00')
        ,('B', '2001-01-02 21:00:00', '2001-01-03 02:00:00')
        ,('C', '2001-01-03 02:00:00', '2001-01-04 00:00:00');

WITH cte AS(
    SELECT      1 AS lvl,
                Employee,
                CONVERT(DATE, StartTime) StartTime_DATE,
                StartTime,
                EndTime
    FROM        @t AS t

    UNION ALL

    SELECT      lvl + 1 AS lvl,
                c.employee,
                DATEADD(d, 1, c.StartTime_DATE) StartTime_DATE,
                c.StartTime,
                c.EndTime
    FROM        cte AS c
    WHERE       DATEADD(d, 1, c.StartTime_DATE) < c.EndTime
),
cteCalc AS(
  SELECT        *
                ,CONVERT(DATE, StartTime) AS StartDate
                ,case lvl
                    when 1 then StartTime
                    else CAST(StartTime_DATE as datetime)
                end as StartTimeNew
                ,case
                    when CAST(EndTime as date) = StartTime_DATE
                        then EndTime
                    else CAST(dateadd(day, 1, StartTime_DATE) as datetime)
                end as EndTimeNew
    FROM        cte
)
SELECT      Employee,
            StartTime_DATE AS StartDate,
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTimeNew, EndTimeNew)/60.0 AS WorkHours
FROM        cteCalc
ORDER BY    Employee, StartTime_DATE
OPTION      (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

---

Edit: I recommend the CTE solution by Tyron78, it performs better then mine in my tests even with large date-ranges - really nice !!!
One fix for that: change this line:

- WHERE DATEADD(d, 1, c.StartTime_DATE) <**=** c.EndTime

to this

- WHERE DATEADD(d, 1, c.StartTime_DATE) < c.EndTime

to account for end-time = midnight.

Really nice one, learned something, thanks!

---

My solution is similar to the calendar lookup, it uses a function intTable(@minValue int, @maxValue int).

```
begin transaction
go

-- create table for sample data
create table #Employee(
    Employee varchar(255) not null,
    StartTime datetime not null,
    EndTime datetime not null
)
go

-- insert sample data, Employees C and D are for testing midnight and 'more then one day' situation
insert into #Employee(Employee, StartTime, EndTime)
values  ('A', convert(datetime, '01/01/2001 23:00', 103), convert(datetime, '02/01/2001 10:0', 103)),
        ('B', convert(datetime, '01/01/2001 21:00', 103), convert(datetime, '01/01/2001 22:00', 103)),
        ('C', convert(datetime, '01/01/2001 00:00', 103), convert(datetime, '02/01/2001 00:00', 103)),
        ('D', convert(datetime, '01/01/2001 23:59', 103), convert(datetime, '03/01/2001 10:07', 103))
go

-- we need a function to create a table of integers from a start to end point
create function intTable(@minValue int, @maxValue int)
    returns @Integers table ( value int )
AS
begin
    declare @Index    int
    set @Index = @minValue
    while @Index <= @MaxValue
    begin
        insert into @Integers ( value ) VALUES ( @Index )
        set @Index = @Index + 1
    end
    return
end
go      

/*
variables for start and end of date range
I don't recommend running this on large data sets with a long date-range !!!
Best create a stored procedure or table-valued udf with 2 dates as input
*/
declare @fromDate date, @toDate date
-- set start/end of date-range
select  @fromDate = min(StartTime),
        @toDate = max(EndTime)
from    #Employee           

;
/*
create a table of ints for the date-range
then create day start/end times for each day of the date-range
*/
with dateRange(dayStart, dayEnd) as (
    select  convert(datetime, dateAdd(day, ints.value, @fromDate)) dayStart,
            convert(datetime, dateAdd(day, ints.value + 1, @fromDate)) dayEnd
    from    intTable(0, datediff(day, @fromDate, @Todate)) ints
)

select      *,
            datediff(hour, 0, dayEmplTimeWorked.TimeWorked) HoursWorked,
            datepart(minute, dayEmplTimeWorked.TimeWorked) MinutesWorked
from        (
                select      dayEmployee.Employee,
                            convert(date, dayEmployee.dayStart) Date,
                            dayEmployee.dayEndTime - dayEmployee.dayStartTime TimeWorked
                from        (
                    select      Employee.Employee,
                                dateRange.dayStart,
                                case when Employee.StartTime >= dateRange.dayStart then Employee.StartTime else dateRange.dayStart end dayStartTime,
                                case when Employee.EndTime >= dateRange.dayEnd then dateRange.dayEnd else Employee.EndTime end dayEndTime
                        from    dateRange
                                inner join
                                #Employee Employee
                                on  /*
                                    find overlaps between then 2 time ranges:
                                        dayStart - dayEnd vs. StartTime - EndTime   
                                    3 'between' comparisons, we don't need the fourth
                                    can't use BETWEEN since we dont want EndTime=midnight to account 0 minutes for next day
                                    */
                                    (
                                        dateRange.dayStart >= Employee.StartTime
                                        and
                                        dateRange.dayStart < Employee.EndTime
                                    )
                                    or
                                    (
                                        dateRange.dayEnd > Employee.StartTime
                                        and
                                        dateRange.dayEnd <= Employee.EndTime
                                    )
                                    or
                                    (
                                        Employee.StartTime >= dateRange.dayStart
                                        and
                                        Employee.StartTime < dateRange.dayEnd
                                    )
                            ) dayEmployee
            ) dayEmplTimeWorked
order by    dayEmplTimeWorked.Employee,
            dayEmplTimeWorked.Date

-- cleanup
drop function intTable
go

drop table #Employee
go

rollback transaction
```